# How to send a form-data POST request with VBA in Excel using WinHTTPRequest

Tags: excel, vba, winhttp, fastapi, winhttprequest

I am building an API using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/first-steps/) that must be accessible from Excel VBA. FastAPI's OAuth2 authentication mechanism requires me to send a "form-data" POST request, but I don't know how to do this using WinHTTPRequest in VBA.

I already have a function which get plain JSON from the API, but this is a GET function and I'm not sure where to specify the "form-data" part in the body, nor where to put the username and password key-value pairs.

Here is a simple VBA GET that handles some errors. How would I modify this to do a form-data POST with username and password fields?

```
Public Function getreq(url As String)
    Dim req As WinHttpRequest
    Dim JsonString As String
    Dim jp As Object
    Dim resp As String
    Dim errorstring As String

    Set req = New WinHttpRequest
    ' req.SetRequestHeaderxxx ?
    ' this is where auth will go via POST form-data username and password?
    req.Open "GET", url
    On Error GoTo errhand:
        req.Send
        resp = req.ResponseText
        If resp = "Internal Server Error" Then
            resp = "{'error': 'Internal server error'}"
        End If
        getreq = resp
    Exit Function

errhand:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147012894 'Code for Timeout
            getreq = "{'error': 'Request timeout'}"
        Case -2147012891 'Code for Invalid URL
            getreq = "{'error': 'Bad url'}"
        Case -2147012867 'Code for Invalid URL
            getreq = "{'error': 'Cannot establish connection'}"
        Case Else 'Add more Errorcodes here if wanted
            errorstring = "Errornumber: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Errordescription: " & Error(Err.Number)
            getreq = "{'error': '" & errorstring & "'}"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Does this [VBA POST json to API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015207/vba-post-json-to-api) help? Authentication credentials are usually sent via `SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "basic " + Base64Encode(PasswordnUsername)` if basic authentication is used.

Comment: No because your example is content-type JSON and I need form-data.

Comment: Doesn't make much difference I think. Have a look here [XmlHttpRequest – Http requests in Excel VBA](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) this is sending form data.

Comment: Still I don't see any reason to stick with the WinHTTPRequest. Is there any? But check my answer below. Actually the structure is always very similar no matter if you end up using `WinHTTPRequest` or `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` or `MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of opening a GET request `req.Open "GET", url` you need to open a `POST`

```
req.Open "POST", url, False
```

Then you can use `setRequestHeader` to set which content type you are going to send and what you accept in return.

```
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
```

For authorization you would also need to create a request header. This depends on what your API uses.

```
req.setRequestHeader "Authorization:", "Bearer " & EncodeBase64("Your-access-token")
```

Finally you send your request

```
req.send (YourData)
```

Have a look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266809/3219613) which shows how the data structure for `multipart/form-data` is generated.

---

If a WinHTTPRequest does not work I recommend to try the following

```
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
URL = "https:///commercial/payments-processing/v1/test/token"
objHttp.Open "POST", URL, False
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization:", "Bearer [Access Token]"
objHttp.send (strPaylodValue)
strResponseStatus = objHttp.Status
strResponseText = objHttp.ResponseText
strResponseText = CStr(strResponseText)
```