Post JSON request in word VBA
How can I post a JSON request to a particular API while incorporating variables?

You could use cURL. Google curl for VBA

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021540/post-json-to-web-in-excel-vba or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015207/vba-post-json-to-api for example

For this example, I posted to discord webhook.
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim Json As String
Json = "{""content"":""Howdy partner!"",""embeds"":null}"

Dim result As String

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/guildid/webhookid"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
objHTTP.send (Json)
result = objHTTP.responseText

Set objHTTP = Nothing

Replace the URL with your URL and edit the JSON as you would like, but note JSON requires double quotes.
Here is an example of incorporating variables into the json:
Dim VARIABLE as String
VARIABLE = "Howdy!"
Json = "{""content"":""" & VARIABLE & """,""embeds"":null}"

